# Devcontainer and Docker: "Error response from daemon: can't access specified distro mount service"

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio-code, devcontainer

### What I intend to do

I give this link to users of a C++ library to open a Visual Studio Code devcontainer: https://vscode.dev/redirect?url=vscode://ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/cloneInVolume?url=https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CoaTL

The project `.devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "C++",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/app,type=bind",
    "workspaceFolder": "/app",
    "build": {
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile-ubuntu"
    },
    "onCreateCommand": "chmod +x .devcontainer/onCreateCommand.sh && ./.devcontainer/onCreateCommand.sh",
    "remoteUser": "root",
    "features": {},
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {},
            "extensions": [
                "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends\
                    vim \
                    git \
                    gcc-12 \
                    g++-12 \
                    build-essential \
                    libboost-all-dev \
                    cmake \
                    unzip \
                    tar \
                    ca-certificates \
                    doxygen \
                    graphviz \ 
                    python3-pip
                    
RUN pip install conan==2.0.13
```

### The issue

It runs fine on MacOS but fails on Windows 10 with this error:

```
[8790 ms] Start: Run: docker run --sig-proxy=false -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=volume,src=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f,dst=/workspaces --mount type=volume,src=vscode,dst=/vscode --mount type=bind,src=\\wsl.localhost\Debian\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,dst=/tmp/vscode-wayland-4930276d-b9ed-41ae-b7ff-43fae90d98f8.sock -l vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CoaTL -l vsch.local.repository.volume=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f -l vsch.local.repository.folder=quetzal-CoaTL -l devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/quetzal-CoaTL/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-quetzal-coatl-02809b04e4fcad285e7f171ed27d137810403cb927ece4767844b9e5dc6fdf42 -c echo Container started
docker: Error response from daemon: can't access specified distro mount service: stat /run/guest-services/distro-services/debian.sock: no such file or directory.
See 'docker run --help'.
[8813 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CoaTL --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=quetzal-CoaTL --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/quetzal-CoaTL/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[8834 ms] Error: Command failed: docker run --sig-proxy=false -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=volume,src=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f,dst=/workspaces --mount type=volume,src=vscode,dst=/vscode --mount type=bind,src=\\wsl.localhost\Debian\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,dst=/tmp/vscode-wayland-4930276d-b9ed-41ae-b7ff-43fae90d98f8.sock -l vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CoaTL -l vsch.local.repository.volume=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f -l vsch.local.repository.folder=quetzal-CoaTL -l devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/quetzal-CoaTL/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-quetzal-coatl-02809b04e4fcad285e7f171ed27d137810403cb927ece4767844b9e5dc6fdf42 -c echo Container started
[8834 ms] trap "exit 0" 15
[8834 ms] exec "$@"
[8834 ms] while sleep 1 & wait $!; do :; done -
[8834 ms] at J$ (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:462:1253)
[8834 ms] at $J (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:462:997)
[8834 ms] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[8834 ms] at async tAA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:479:3660)
[8834 ms] at async CC (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:479:4775)
[8834 ms] at async NeA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:612:11107)
[8835 ms] at async MeA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:612:10848)
[8851 ms] Exit code 1
[8852 ms] Start: Run: docker rm -f 806247e22a3aaac72ceb1f03d6ba197bf4484441e49b076ffc82ac15f9a82304
[8854 ms] Command failed: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-c1621933-f7af-4f4b-befc-08cfd85ec89d1703170006449 --workspace-folder /workspaces/quetzal-CoaTL --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CoaTL --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=quetzal-CoaTL --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/quetzal-CoaTL/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/quetzal-CoaTL/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --override-config /tmp/devcontainer-91916c56-d489-4cb7-95e8-9d09240eddee.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=quetzal-CoaTL-6543d175a18dda8f2bcd1eb175a9e982510924f869315542b381993ba2369d0f,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=\\wsl.localhost\Debian\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-4930276d-b9ed-41ae-b7ff-43fae90d98f8.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root --terminal-columns 225 --terminal-rows 15
[8854 ms] Exit code 1
[8990 ms] Container server terminated (code: 137, signal: null).
```

I struggle debugging this, being newish to devcontainers and not knowing where to start from.

Why would Docker try to run `stat /run/guest-services/distro-services/debian.sock` (and not find it)?

Comment: I got this exact same issue. did you find a fix @Waterfox?

Comment: @KillerSnail not yet, haven't had the time to work on it :) I believe it is a platform problem ( see https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/ ) but it's just a wild guess!